# How to run Flutter app on iOS simulator on macmini from Windows

Tags: android, ios, windows, macos, flutter

I am about to start doing development with Flutter so I can deploy an app on Android and iOS. I am using Windows 10 as the OS for doing development, so I can run Android Studio and Visual Studio Code to do the development and also test on Android emulator. I have a new MacMini that I would like to use to test my iOS app using the iPhone simulator. The MacMini and my Windows box are in the same local network.
How can I run and test my app for iOS devices using the MacMini from my Windows box? And is it possible to see the iOS simulator from my Windows box, similar to the Android emulator, but via something like VNC or remote view? Thank you!